# XAML Binding to a converter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

what I am trying to do is relatively simple.  I am just trying to bind the Y element of a TranslateTransform on an ellipse to 1/2 the height of the ellipse:

```
    <Ellipse Name="EllipseOnlyLFA" Height="200" Fill="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Ellipse.Width>
            <Binding ElementName="EllipseOnlyLFA" Path="Height"/>
        </Ellipse.Width>
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform>
                <TranslateTransform.Y>
                    <Binding Converter="MultiplyByFactor" ElementName="EllipseOnlyLFA" Path="Height"  ConverterParameter="0.5"/>
                </TranslateTransform.Y>
            </TranslateTransform>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
```

I also have the following converter:

```
public class MultiplyByFactor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value * (double)parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on the XAML line where I actually use the converter.  The error is

> 'Set property
>   'System.Windows.Data.Binding.Converter'
>   threw an exception.' Line number '22'
>   and line position '8'.

Can anyone shed some light on how to do this?  **EDIT: Yes, I have the converter added as a resource.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are 2 thing wrong with your code

1) your converter needs to be accessed using the `StaticResource` declaration

```
<Binding Converter="{StaticResource myMultiplyByFactor}" 
    ElementName="EllipseOnlyLFA" Path="Height"  ConverterParameter="0.5"/
```

2) Your converter parameter is a string by default, so you need to convert it to a double

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    double.TryParse((parameter as string).Replace(',', '.'), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double param);
    return param * (double)value;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to add the converter to the resources

**Edit**
You need to add the namespace too

```
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

**end edit**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:MultiplyByFactor x:Key="myMultiplyByFactor"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then you can use the instance from the resources

```
<TranslateTransform.Y>
    <Binding Converter={StaticResource myMultiplyByFactor}"
        ElementName="EllipseOnlyLFA"
        Path="Height" ConverterParameter="0.5"/>
</TranslateTransform.Y>
```

Comment: @Albin - It should be Converter={StaticResource myMultiplyByFactor}

Comment: I don't think the downvote is necessary, since the idea here is right.

Comment: Thanks, Albin.  I appreciate your thoroughness.  I have it working now!

Answer (score 0):

The Parameter probably gets passed as a String. Set a breakpoint in your Converter and look at the values of `value` and `parameter`. You might need to use double.Parse instead of the cast.