# Can't properly load a ResourceDictionary at runtime

Tags: wpf, vb.net, resourcedictionary

**Note**: I have a ResourceDictionary and WPF Window (my View) and ViewModel, all declared within a **WinForms** application. Therefore I have no App.xaml.

I have the following converter declared:

```
Public Class DebugConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
        Return value
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

And then I try loading a ResourceDictionary at runtime (which I specified the build action as Resource and not Page):

```
 m_rdGridDictionary = New ResourceDictionary()
 m_rdGridDictionary.Source = New Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPF/Helpers/GridResourceDictionary.xaml")
```

In the ResourceDictionary I have it declared as such:

```
<ResourceDictionary
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:cnv="clr-namespace:Positron.Cad.WindowGUI.WPFConverters">

     <cnv:DebugConverter x:Key="DebugConverter"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But when I try loading the ResourceDictionary, it cannot find the converter:

[image: Error]

Would anyone know what is wrong with this scenario? They both exist in the same namespaces, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Please add your code as text not as image and include the appropriate part of GridResourceDictionary.xaml (referencing the DebugConverter). A reference to the converter is probably wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253554/xaml-binding-to-a-converter

Comment: Can you post the code for where you're attempting to "load" the converter.

Comment: I've updated my post, sorry for that, I had little time when I first posted...

Comment: Is DebugConverter in the same assembly with ResourceDictionary? Otherwise you need to specify assembly in "xmlns:cnv=..." too

Comment: Yes it's in the same project.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!  The Build action had to be Page and not Resource.