# AvaloniaUI: Logic in xaml

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

Can I use logic in xaml e.g.

```
IsVisible="{Binding OnlyTraverseSelectedSection != null ? true : false}"
```

in some way?

Comment: Afaik you cannot use logic like this in xaml itself but you could create a [Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4253554/205233).

Comment: Bind to a property which contains the logic.

Comment: I know, but I thought there is a way in avalonia

Answer (score 2):

You can't currently use expressions in bindings - I would love for that to be the case but we're not there yet!

Having said that, there is one kind-of expression you can use in binding - the negation operator:

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/docs/spec/binding-from-xaml.md#negating-bindings

An example:

`<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding !HasErrors}"/>`

Comment: Are we any closer to this today?

Comment: Any news in 2023? Btw. Provided link is dead. But here you can see an example: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/guides/data-binding/binding-classes#example