# How to set a button size regarding the height of its container in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, sizing

I am developping a WPF application in XAML. I am a beginner and I have an issue with my button. I need to set its height as a proportion of its container which is a grid. I saw that the height can be set to a value or to "Auto", but I don't know how to say to my button that his height must be 3/4 of the height of the grid in which it is contained.

Does anybody know how to deal with that ? Is it possible to do that with XAML ?

The objective is that when the grid grows, the button grows with it.

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks

Here is the code I wrote :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppButtonSize.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppButtonSize"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Grid>
    <Grid Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Button 1" FontSize="30" Height="75" Width="150"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

For the button, instead of Height="75", I would like to say Height=0.75 * Grid Height

Comment: Is this WPF, Xamarin or MAUI?

Comment: It's a WPF application I'm trying to develop.

Comment: Please show some code and what you have tried so far

Comment: I added it to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your Grid and your Button a name by specifying the `x:Name` attribute, you could set the Button's `Height` in the code behind whenever the Grid's size changes.

**XAML**

```xml
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Button x:Name="MyButton" />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

In WPF you could then do this in the code-behind:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    MyGrid.SizeChanged += (s,e) =>
    {
        if(e.HeightChanged)
        {
            MyButton.Height = MyGrid.Height * 0.75;
        }
    }
}
```

while in other .NET technologies, such as Xamarin.Forms or .NET MAUI it would have to look like this:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    MyGrid.PropertyChanged += (s,e) =>
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == nameof(MyGrid.Height))
        {
            MyButton.Height = MyGrid.Height * 0.75;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code but I got the following error : 
CS1061 Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Grid' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyChanged' and no accessible extension method 'PropertyChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'Grid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
I tried several fixed and finally it works.

Comment: I used the following code :
            
                
MyGrid.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.HeightChanged)
                {
                    MyButton.Height = MyGrid.Height * 0.2;
                }
            };

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to place the button within its own grid, with rows sized approporiately to generate the spacing.

e.g.

```
<Grid ...>

    <Grid Grid.Row="???" Grid.Column="???" ...>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
        <Button Grid.Row="0" ... />
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not exactly what I want to do. I want to do calculations in XAML to define the height of my button. And I want to link the height of my button to the height of the grid. But I don't know if it is possible with XAML. Do you understand what I mean ? Maybe it is necessary to use XAML combined with C# to achieve that ?

Comment: @iDppma You cannot do calculations in XAML. You can only do that in the code behind (C# part of your view)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't knew if it was possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using converter and binding "ActualHeight" property of Grid.

```
<Button Height="{Binding ElementName="mygGrid" Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource percentageConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: That's not a bad idea. You should also show how the `PercentageConverter` is defined and added to the Resources for completeness sake and future readers. Also, it may be useful to add a converter parameter, so that the value isn't hard coded in the converter implementation.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I tried using converter, binding and converter parameter and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I succeded using the following :

1. Creating a new class Converters with Convert function

**Converters.cs**

```
namespace WpfAppButtonSize 
{
public class Converters : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double.TryParse((parameter as string).Replace(',', '.'), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double param);
        return param * (double)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

2. Bind the actual height of my button to the height of my grid + use the converter as a static resouce and a converter parameter

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converter:Converters x:Key="converter" />
</Window.Resources>
    
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Height="100" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="Button 1" FontSize="30" Width="150" Height="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource converter}, ConverterParameter=0.75}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**And dont forget to add the converter namespace to the xaml :**

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:WpfAppButtonSize"
```

The following post also helped me : [XAML Binding to a converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253554/xaml-binding-to-a-converter)

Thank you all for your help.